# Which Aws support Alexa skills

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

From several tutorials regarding Alexa Skill development, it's known that only a set of AWS Regions support Alexa Skill Lambda functions.
Statements like:

```
10.  IMPORTANT: Select EU West (Dublin, Ireland) region (upper right). Only eu-west-1 (Dublin) and us-east-1 (N.Virginia) AWS regions currently support the Alexa Skills Kit and lambda integration.
```

Can be found here: 
https://developer.amazon.com/de/blogs/alexa/post/tx2xuaq741iyqi4/how-to-build-a-multi-language-alexa-skill

And here:
https://developer.amazon.com/de/alexa-skills-kit/alexa-skill-quick-start-tutorial

UPDATE:
And I found the following note here:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-lambda-function

```
Note: Lambda functions for Alexa skills can be hosted in either the US East (N. Virginia) or EU (Ireland) region. These are the only regions the Alexa Skills Kit supports.
```

Now the tutorials and the doc might not be up to date, and it could be possible that now all regions support it, but how can we look up, which regions are supporting Alexa skills and which not?

Comment: What does the API say?

Comment: Either nothing or I was not able to find it.

Comment: PS i found a not on this page: https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-lambda-function

Comment: This question is ill-suited for Stack Overflow, since the list of regions will keep changing and the only reliable source for this information is the AWS documentation.

Comment: For regions that support alexa, you will find a option to add alexa trigger to your lambda methods. For regions that do not support alexa, you wont find that option.

Answer (score 1):

As you said before: Only US East (N. Virginia) and EU West (Ireland) can support Alexa Voice Services. You have to select while creating the Lambda function.

Even if they open new regions for Alexa, what will defnetly happend, you can export and import your Lambda function to another region.

Hope, that I could help you

Answer (score 1):

According to this page, Tokyo and Oregon are also Alexa compatible at the moment:
https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html#create-a-lambda-function-for-an-alexa-skill

> Click the region drop-down in the upper-right corner of the console and select one of the regions supported for Alexa skills: *Asia Pacific (Tokyo), EU (Ireland), US East (N. Virginia), or US West (Oregon)*.

There's one method I know to test, wether a region is supported:
Create a dummy lambda function in the region you want to test. Copy the ARN of this lambda. Try to add it as an endpoint to one of your skills (might also be a dummy one). If the region isn't supported, you will get an error and the tool won't let you add that ARN.